# iOS Push Notification policy

Tags: ios, push-notification, policy

I'd like to implement a push notification service in my iPad app. But before I do that I have to know further details about its contraints.

I know that the user has to accept the apps notification ability. But is that only for notifications which come in when the app is in the background or also when the app is active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user doesn't need to accept the ability to allow Push Notifications but they can turn them off from the Settings app. This will turn off all incoming push notifications if the app is in the Background. If your app is running:

> If the application is running when the notification arrives, no alert is displayed or icon badged or sound played, even if (in iOS) the device screen is locked. Instead, the application delegate is informed of the notification and can handle it directly.

You can find loads more information on Push Notifications in [Apple's Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html)